# get the result of escpos commands program on my machine without using printer

Tags: javascript, node.js, emulation, escpos

I wrote a program using escpos commands and I wanna get the result of this program without using a printer!

```
ESC = SOH GS ( J STX NULL SOH NULL GS ( J STX NULL STX NULL GS ( J STX NULL ETX NULL ESC c 0 STX ESC c 1 STX ESC c 3 NULL ESC 2 ESC R NULL ESC t DLE GS b SOH GS P NULL NULL ESC J NULL ESC J ÿ ESC J  ESC $  NULL GS 8 L · 4 NULL NULL 0 p 0 SOH SOH 1 ø NULL ³ SOH NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL à NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL à NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL à NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL SOH þ NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL SO NULL NULL NULL ETX  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL BEL ÿ NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL SO NULL NULL NULL ETX  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL BEL ETX NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

is there any tool that i can use it to put the code and get the result?

Comment: There seems to be no confirmation method that is better than physical printers, but these articles may be helpful. [dacduong/escpos-printer-simulator](https://github.com/dacduong/escpos-printer-simulator), [Virtual ESC POS printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55398308/9014308), [How use thermal printer(USB/Ethernet) on android, without using vendor SDK,?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47524508/9014308), [How to print raw ESC/POS commands from Javascript](https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-Javascript/)

Comment: @kunif i checked this but it doesn't work, I want just a software where i can put the code escpos and get the result on my machine without using any printer

Comment: What about other things like this? [receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools), [SnailDev/SnailDev.EscPosParser](https://github.com/SnailDev/SnailDev.EscPosParser) Even if you can't use it directly, how about using these as parts and creating your own programs?

Comment: @kunif I don't want using programs especially with php I want to do it easily without programming or with javascript and node js, is there any way?

Comment: You can find these in Node.js related software. [taoyuan/npos](https://github.com/taoyuan/npos), [escpos-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos-parser)

Comment: @kunif I use https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools and https://wkhtmltopdf.org. I install php 7 and the composer. but i don't know how to make it work

Comment: I have never used it, so I cannot give specific advice. See the author's article here. [Mike's Software Blog TAG: ESCPOS-PHP](https://mike42.me/blog/tag/escpos-php), [What is ESC/POS, and how do I use it?](https://mike42.me/blog/what-is-escpos-and-how-do-i-use-it), [escpos-tools/esc2html.php](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools/blob/master/esc2html.php)

Comment: @Julia skip the wkhtmltopdf you only need that if you want to convert the file to pdf.  Have your program send the output to a file, then execute    "php esc2html.php filename > filename.html".  You can view the .html file on any browser.

Comment: @ kunif, have you used SnailDev/SnailDev.EscPosParser?  How well does it work? I have used  receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools and it is good as long as your escpos files don't get too complicated... which they always seem to do.

Comment: @mw, It is not used. Looking at the source, it seems that only commonly used commands that the author needed are supported.